# Get all values from checkboxes?

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

Is there an easy way to get the values of multiple checkboxes and store them in the database?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['go'])){
   $fruit = $_POST['fruit'].",";
   echo $fruit;
   // if you selected apple and grapefruit it would display apple,grapefruit
}
?>
<form method="post">
Select your favorite fruit:<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple" /><label for="apple">Apple</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="pinapple" id="pinapple" /><label for="pinapple">Pinapple</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="grapefruit" id="grapefruit" /><label for="grapefruit">Grapefruit</label><br />
<input type="submit" name="go" />
</form>
```

Comment: change `name="fruit"` to `name="fruit[]"`, remove `$fruit = $_POST...`, change `echo $fruit;` to `echo implode(',',$_POST['fruit'])`

Comment: name the checkboxes "name=fruit[]" so they will be sent to an array

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you give the checkboxes the same name, ending in [], the values are returned as an array.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple" />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="grapefruit" />
```

Then in PHP ...

```
if( isset($_POST['fruit']) && is_array($_POST['fruit']) ) {
    foreach($_POST['fruit'] as $fruit) {
        // eg. "I have a grapefruit!"
        echo "I have a {$fruit}!";
        // -- insert into database call might go here
    }

    // eg. "apple, grapefruit"
    $fruitList = implode(', ', $_POST['fruit']);
    // -- insert into database call (for fruitList) might go here.
}
```

PS. please forgive the obvious error, that this example will potentially shout "I have a apple" ... I didn't think to make the example smart enough to determine when to use "a", and when to use "an" :P

Answer (score 5):

Name your input like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple" id="apple" /><label for="apple">Apple</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="pinapple" id="pinapple" /><label for="pinapple">Pinapple</label><br />
```

Then iterate on the $_POST['fruit'] :

```
if(isset($_POST['fruit']) && !empty($_POST['fruit']))   
    foreach($_POST['fruit'] as $fruit) echo $fruit;
```

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the other solutions...

implode and explode can be used in PHP to convert your array of fruit[] into a comma seperated list.

```
$valueToStoreInDB = implode(",",$_POST['fruit']);
$fruitAsAnArrayAgain[] = explode(",",$dbvalue);
```

Once you have your comma separated list, a good data type to represent the checkboxes in MySQL would be [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html), and you can paste your comma seperated list right into your insert statement.